# Is it possible to create a new multisite site via a Craft Plugin/Module?

Tags: plugin-development, multi-site

Does Craft provide a way to programmatically add a new multisite site through a plugin or module?

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the same APIs that Craft itself has; so sure, you could programmatically create new sites via a plugin or module.